# I cannot start the server nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wanted to install npm cache for nodejs. However as soon as i installed i started working to create a cache file, when i saved i got an error like this below. i tried multiple methods like: deleted files: package-lock.json, package.json and reinstalled but its didn't work. Anyone have an idea of ​​the problem? thanks in advance

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json  
[nodemon] starting `node start server.js`   
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dossa\Documents\projet_perso\fullStack\loc_cars\backend\start'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: `node start server.js` --> `node server.js`

Comment: Does the file `C:\Users\dossa\Documents\projet_perso\fullStack\loc_cars\backend\start.js` exist?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by repeating the removal of the package-lock.json and node-module files several times. Thank for response